# How to run a rails application in another computer while still coding in my own computer?

Tags: linux, ssh, network-programming, server

I have an iMac and when develop in Ruby on Rails I run everything on it: MySQL server, Redis service, ElasticSearch service, guard, and, of course, the proper `rails server`. By doing so, my computer runs pretty slow.

So I just bought a CPU and install linux in it, along with MySQL, Redis & ElasticSearch. Now I connect to that services from my iMac and it runs way faster.

However, Rspec/Guard still takes ages to load/run.
So, how do I make the linux server to take the hit and actually run this programs while I keep editing the code in my mac?

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be a crude way and i haven't tested it

1. Place your project in Dropbox folder on your machine and have it open on the second computer
2. Run it on the quick machine. You can use following command to access it through ip address on the computers in same network

   rails server -b 192.168.1.12 -p 8000
3. When saving code it should sync from one machine to another, may have slight delay for syncing

or set up Vagrant.

Thats the only ways I can see.